# Google Form/Sheets send alert emails automatically based on cell data

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a Google Form setup as a COVID-19 questionnaire for people working onsite. They are required to fill it out each day they work onsite. It is built in four languages. The Form is of course linked to a Google Sheet. What we are trying to do is send an email alert to specific managers anytime someone answers YES to one of the questions. That is YES in English, Spanish, Albanian and Nepali. So far we have it setup and the email alert will include the person's Name, Department and any questions they answered YES to. But it is also pulling the Name and Department headers from every one of the language columns as well. Some of the non-English question column headers have a Note inserted (a quick translation) that we would like to include in the email alert as well - but have not included that yet - would like advice on how to include the Note if possible. This is what the alert emails look like.

Nombre:

नाम:

In the past 14 days have you traveled outside of Oregon? This applies to non-essential travel.: Yes

विभाग (वा संग्रहालय सम्पर्क):

Departamento (o Contacto del Museo):

Name: VS

Departamenti (ose Kontakti i Muzeut):

Emri:

Department (or Museum Contact): PS

In the past 14 days have you been in close proximity to anyone who has traveled outside of Oregon? This applies to non-essential travel and if you were around people from out of state who did not quarantine upon arrival.: Yes

Currently (or in the past 14 days) have you, or anyone you have been in close proximity to, tested positive, been defined as presumptively positive or are waiting for test results for COVID-19?: Yes

Currently (or in the past 14 days) are you, or anyone you have been in close proximity to, experiencing any of the following symptoms that cannot be attributed to a previously diagnosed, underlying or recently resolved condition?: Yes

```
  function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var values = e.namedValues;
  var htmlBody = '<ol>';
  var containsYes = 0;
  
  for (Key in values) {
    var label = Key;
    var data = values[Key];
    
    
    if ((label == "Name") || (label == "Department (or Museum Contact)"))
    {
      htmlBody += '<li>'+label+': <strong style="color:RED;">'+data+'</strong></li>';

    }
    
    if ((label == "Nombre") || (label == "Departamento (o Contacto del Museo)"))
    {
      htmlBody += '<li>'+label+': <strong style="color:RED;">'+data+'</strong></li>';

    }

    if ((label == "Emri") || (label == "Departamenti (ose Kontakti i Muzeut)"))
    {
      htmlBody += '<li>'+label+': <strong style="color:RED;">'+data+'</strong></li>';

    }

    if ((label == "नाम") || (label == "विभाग (वा संग्रहालय सम्पर्क)"))
    {
      htmlBody += '<li>'+label+': <strong style="color:RED;">'+data+'</strong></li>';

    }

    else if (data == 'Yes')
    {
      containsYes += 1;
      htmlBody += '<li>'+label+': <strong style="color:RED;">' + data + '</strong></li>';
    }
    
    else if (data == 'Sí')
    {
      containsYes += 1;
      htmlBody += '<li>'+label+': <strong style="color:RED;">' + data + '</strong></li>';
    }

    else if (data == 'Po')
    {
      containsYes += 1;
      htmlBody += '<li>'+label+': <strong style="color:RED;">' + data + '</strong></li>';
    }

    else if (data == 'हो')
    {
      containsYes += 1;
      htmlBody += '<li>'+label+': <strong style="color:RED;">' + data + '</strong></li>';
    }

    else
    {
      continue;
    }
    
    
  }; // END FOR LOOP
  
  htmlBody += '</ol>';
  if (containsYes > 0)
  {
    GmailApp.sendEmail('sample@gmail.com','Alert! COVID-19 Screening','', {htmlBody:htmlBody})
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the Sheet. It doesn't show all of the languages, but hopefully this illustrates the overall layout.

[Sheetscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqb3r.png)

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question does fall into the range of questions for this forum because it requires us to give you an opinion.  Please rewrite the question and focus it down to single problem with you code.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the string inside the parenthesis if the header have notes?

Comment: I'll try approaching this from a different angle. We have a questionnaire in four languages: English, Spanish, Albanian and Nepali. The first section of the Google Form has the person select the language. From there they go to the questionnaire in the language selected. They enter their name and answer 4 questions. Can the name and questions all get dumped into a designated column? Question #1 from all languages goes to column D. Question #2 from all languages goes to column E. Then a Yes answer (in any language) triggers an email that includes the person's name and question they answered Yes.